# Create a report to MS Word from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word, report

I want to create a report of some database tables to word document. I know, It's possible to do using namespace **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;**

Now I can create word document with a simple string using this code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

private void MakeReport()
{
    object fileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\DataBase_Report.docx";

    Word.Application WordApplication = new Word.Application();
    WordApplication.Visible = true;

    Word.Document WordDocument = WordApplication.Documents.Open(fileName);
    WordDocument.Variables["DataBase"].Value = "Hello";

    WordDocument.Fields.Update();
    WordDocument.Save();
}
```

Does anybody know, how to out table to this document?

Comment: Why not just create Excel report ?

Comment: Because that's my task.

Comment: look for word's insertdatabase method, and oprionally postprocess to modify formatting/layout.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very old trick I came across a while back, an it might not satisfy all your requirements, but I think it's worth mentioning.

You can add two headers to any aspx page that will cause the browser to download the page instead of rendering it. You can design your page like you would normally, then add these two headers

```
Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/vnd.ms-word")
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & "SomeFileName.doc")
```

b.t.w if you need excel, you can change them like this

```
Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/vnd.ms-excel")
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & "SomeFileName.xls")
```

The limitations I can think of are

- It's not actually a word document. It's a HTML document with a .doc
  extension
- No relative path's supported
- You might get some warnings on the client that the file type doesn't match the content of the document
- .docx and .xlsx is not supported. Only .doc and .xls

I you can live with that, it's the easiest way I know of to generate office documents without any third party tools.

Comment: thank you. But I'm using a simple Windows Forms app. I have a ListView with list of people and I have to generate a report. So I've found solution [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's KB 257757, interop is not recommended if you will be running your application in server environment.

I am using Docentric Toolkit for Word document generation, which is a OpenXML based tool so no Word installation is necessary on the server. The tool comes with a MS Word Add-in, with which you can prepare templates with placeholders for data.

In your application you then have to:

1. Read data from the database into data model class collections (e.g. using Entity Framework and linq)
2. Call the method to generate Word document from the chosen template which is filled with data from data collection from previous step.

You can take a look at an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/759408/Creating-Word-documents-in-Net-using-Docentric-Too) in CodeProject.